# How to find the users within 10miles using latitude and longitude of the user in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-geocoder

I have `latitude` and `longitude` of all the user. I have to find the user who is near to me `(around 10 miles)` from my current latitude and longitude. And i have to give it as response in json. I have tried to configure geokit gem for this but it showed me some error like

```
WARNING: geokit-rails requires the Geokit gem. You either don't have the gem installed,
or you haven't told Rails to require it. If you're using a recent version of Rails: 
  config.gem "geokit" # in config/environment.rb
and of course install the gem: sudo gem install geokit
```

so i have moved to geocoder. What should i do with this geocoder for finding users with the above said conditions? please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  geocoded_by :address

  after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?
end

User.near([latitude, longitude], 10).to_json

# or even simpler since current_user is a geocoded object (i.e has lat/long)

User.near(current_user, 10).to_json
```

Comment: I have tried this and it shows error as NoMethodError (undefined method `near' for #<Class:0x00000102a8f900>)

Comment: Did you set up Geocoder for the User class? Will update my answer if not.

Comment: No i have not. How should i set up?

Comment: Updated. How did you calculate the lat and long for your users? Do they have an address field?

Comment: No actually this latitude and longitude is sent from the iphone app.

Comment: Then you don't need the `after_validation` callback. Also don't bother about the argument of `geocoded_by`, this method is there to include the required modules.

Comment: so should i add the line geocoded_by :address alone in my user model or do i have add to add something as well

Comment: Yes, you have to add `geocoded_by :something` in your model. It includes/extends the modules for the `near` class methods (and some others).

Comment: Thank you so much. It works and i will accept your answer after checking completely.